# SharePoint list change text of term ID to Managed Metadata column

Tags: list, managed-metadata, term

I have a list with 2 columns, both are simple text and in one I have code in other one I have termId for Managed Metadata. What I want to do is create a new Managed Metadata column and then somehow fill it with managed metadata.

I hoped to achieve this via Power Automate, but it uses term ID as value and just throws an error. Is there any way to achieve what I want with this?

Comment: If you have the term Id this should work... What does the error message say? It could be some formatting issue.

Comment: The data returned from the tagging UI was not formatted correctly
clientRequestId: Term-ID I use
serviceRequestId: Term-ID I use

And in the body of update item task I have this:

{
  "Title": "A",
  "Level1ID": "Term-ID I use",
  "Level1Data": {
    "Value": "Term-ID I use"
  }
}

I believe the issue that it checks my ID as value instead of as ID, and there is no term with this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to set this using Power Automate you will also need the term label to be able to format it properly.
Expected format for a custom value is:

```
Term Label|Term Guid
```

Example: `Test|c9579a6a-c0b2-4aa0-84b8-869d53901231`
[image]

You can either update your current text field to include the term label, or incorporate some lookup in your flow if that is not an option. And that is probably worthy of a question by itself :-)